# Ant Design - prevent table row click in specific column/area

Tags: antd

I'm using ant design table component. I have "actions" column that I don't want the onRowClick event will trigger in this column.

How can it be done?

http://codepen.io/liron_e/pen/zZjVKZ?editors=001

```
const { Table, Modal } = antd;

const confirm = (id) => {
  Modal.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm',
    content: 'Bla bla ...',
    okText: 'OK',
    cancelText: 'Cancel',
  });
};

const info = (id) => {
  Modal.info({
    title: 'Info',
    content: 'Bla bla ...',
    okText: 'OK',
    cancelText: 'Cancel',
  });
};

const columns = [
  {
    key: 'status',
    title: 'text',
    dataIndex: 'text'
  }, {
    key: 'actions',
    title: 'actions',
    dataIndex: 'id',
    render: (id) => {
      return (
        <span>
          <a href="#" onClick={() => confirm(id)}>
            Clone
          </a>
          <span className="ant-divider" />
          <a href="#" onClick={() => confirm(id)}>
            Replace
          </a>
        </span>
      );
    }
  }
];

 const dataSource = [
   {
     id: '1',
     text: 'Hello'
   },{
     id: '123',
     text: 'adsaddas'
   },{
     id: '123344',
     text: 'cvbbcvb'
   },{
     id: '5665',
     text: 'aasddasd'
   },
 ];


ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Table 
      columns={columns}
      onRowClick={() => this.info()}
      dataSource={dataSource}
    />
  </div>
, mountNode);
```

As you can try when pressing on row the info modal would open.
When pressing some action the info **and** the confirm modals would open, and I would like that **only confirm modal would open**.

Thanks (:

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your render function:

```
render: (id) => {
  return (
    <span>
      <a href="#" onClick={(e) => { 
           e.stopPropagation();      
           confirm(id);
          }}>
        Clone
      </a>
      <span className="ant-divider" />
      <a href="#" onClick={() => confirm(id)}>
        Replace
      </a>
    </span>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Can you add details to your answer? It would be helpful to state what this does, and why it will solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just stop propagation in your action handler:

`<span>
    <a href="#" onClick={() => confirm(id)}>
        Clone
    </a>
    <span className="ant-divider" />
    <a href="#" onClick={() => confirm(id)}>
        Replace
    </a>
</span>`

Comment: What is the difference here?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Menu.Item onClick={(e)=>{ 
            e.domEvent.stopPropagation();
            handleUpdate(id)}}>
            Edit
 </Menu.Item>
```

Comment: Please, add an explaination.

Answer (score 0):

Using react `Link` we can have a default `anchor` link functionality by stoping event propagation and trigger event on particular column.

- "react-router": "^5.2.0",
- import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

```html
  render: (value, record) => {

 // Conditional checks if needs to handle on particular set of column 

    return (
     <Link to={'TARGET_LINK_HERE'}
          target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"
          onClick={(event) => {
            event.stopPropagation(); // prevent event to propogate to parent to have row click which is default functionality
         }}>{value}</Link>
    ) 
   }
```